# Scaling ThreeJS view on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is ThreeJs render view, just I want to scaling render view based on mobile device/width.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  120,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(1, 1, 1);
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 2, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0));
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  line.rotation.x += 0.1;
  line.rotation.y += 0.8;
  // line.rotation.z += 0.5;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.97.0/build/three.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you asking? `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` are just as valid and just as scaled to their viewport on mobile, so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish at all (or rather, I'm unsure what you are presuming is going wrong)... Also, for the snippet's sake, move the `<script>` for THREE.js inside your body, or remove the `<head>` (stack overflow should take care of that)

Comment: Rendering Element, which is rotating !

Comment: Yes but _what_ is the issue? Do you just want to _zoom in_ a bit on mobile? Technically THREE.js is rendering it exactly right for all screen sizes, so _what_ issue are you trying to solve? What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want to zoom out the `line` element

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your `camera.position.z` based on the width of the viewport or something? Like `camera.position.z = innerWidth / 320` ? I still feel your question is vague. What are you trying to accomplish? Assure that your entire line fills the screen but no more, like `background-position: contain` in css? Or just 'slightly adjust' it for mobile?

Comment: Yeah its works for me, but how can I detect media query particularly **ios** devices and apply this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182325/discussion-between-momin-and-somethinghere).